# Open Dialog instead of Popper in desktop MUI 5 DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the MUI v5 `DatePicker` (@mui/lab 5.0.0-alpha-51) to behave like the `DesktopDatePicker` (allowing to directly edit the date in the textbox). But when clicking on the calendar icon, I want to open the picker dialog, just like when clicking the `MobileDatePicker`.

I tried using the `MobileDatePicker` and added `endAdornment` to the `InputProps` to just get the calendar icon to draw. But this wasn't working.

Perhaps to put it more clearly: I want the `DesktopDatePicker` to open the Dialog of the `MobileDatePicker` when the user clicks on the calendar icon.

Is there a way to achieve this hybrid behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a look at [`MobileWrapper`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-lab/src/internal/pickers/wrappers/MobileWrapper.tsx#L38-L53) and [`DesktopWrapper`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-lab/src/internal/pickers/wrappers/DesktopWrapper.tsx#L34-L43) definitions, you'll see that they use different components to display the picker (the former uses modal, the latter uses popover) and there is no way to swap it using the props provided by the picker component, but you also know where the internal modal comes from, so you can grab it:

```
import PickersModalDialog from "@mui/lab/internal/pickers/PickersModalDialog";
```

In this [section](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#static-mode), you can see that MUI exposes the `StaticDatePicker` which uses the internal `Picker` component that both the desktop and mobile pickers utilize, in case you want to build your own custom popup/modal, this is exactly what you want here, so grab this one too:

```
import StaticDatePicker from '@mui/lab/StaticDatePicker';
```

The next step is to integrate and make them work together, we have the `DesktopDatePicker` because you want to edit the `TextField`, the `PickersModalDialog` to display the `StaticDatePicker` in a modal. To do that you need to do the following things:

- **(1)** Disable the popover picker from the `DesktopDatePicker` or we'll have 2 pickers show up at the same time.
- **(2)** Control the `DesktopDatePicker` date value. The `DesktopDatePicker` requests to change the value when the user edits the `TextField`.
- **(3)** Control the `StaticDatePicker` date value. The `StaticDatePicker` requests to change the value when the user picks a date in the modal.
- **(4)** Control the `PickersModalDialog` open state by overriding the props in the step below.
- **(5)** Add the required props in `PickersModalDialog`:

  - `onAccept`: When the user clicks the **OK** button.
  - `onClear`: When the user clicks the **CANCEL** button.
  - `onSetToday`: When the user clicks the **TODAY** button. Only available in `MobileDatePicker`, if you want to display it, set `showTodayButton` in `PickersModalDialog`.
  - `onDismiss`: When the dialog wants to close itself (for example when the user clicks outside the modal)

Putting it together, we'll have something like below:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(() => new Date()); // (2)
const [tempValue, setTempValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(null); // (3)
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false); // (4)

return (
  <>
    <DesktopDatePicker
      label="For desktop"
      value={value}
      open={false} // (1)
      onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
      onOpen={() => {
        setTempValue(value);
        setOpen(true);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
    <PickersModalDialog
      showTodayButton
      open={open}
      // (5)
      onAccept={() => {
        setValue(tempValue);
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      onSetToday={() => {
        setValue(new Date());
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      onDismiss={() => setOpen(false)}
      onClear={() => setOpen(false)}
    >
      <StaticDatePicker
        displayStaticWrapperAs="mobile"
        value={tempValue}
        onChange={(newValue) => setTempValue(newValue)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </PickersModalDialog>
  </>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]